# How to disable indentation upon entering a semicolon, in Emacs under verilog mode?

Tags: emacs, verilog, system-verilog

Has anyone figured out which *Emacs* customization variable to twiddle, in order to prevent indentation occurring when you enter a semicolon while editing a (System)Verilog file in `verilog` mode?

Thanks,
-db

Answer (score 1):

Try `(setq verilog-auto-newline nil)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It did not fix my problem.

Comment: How about plus `(setq verilog-auto-indent-on-newline nil)`?

Answer (score 0):

verilog-mode maps the `;` key to the function `electric-verilog-semi` , which is fundamental to the emacs mode. Sounds to me like you want to do your **editing** in `text-mode` and **viewing** in `verilog-mode`.